# How to use Animated.timing on a new Animated.ValueXY()

Tags: react-native

With `const animation = new Animated.ValueXY()` I can do

```
Animated.timing(animation, { toValue: 0, duration: 500})
```

How can I accomplish this on both X and Y with `const animation = new Animated.ValueXY()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as initializing the values to `const animation = new Animated.ValueXY({x: 0, y: 0})`:

```
Animated.timing(animation, { 
     toValue: {x: 0, y: 0}, 
     duration: 500
})
```

Behavior is the same for all Animated.ValueXY related operations. `{x: num, y: num}` instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

To complete further from Gabriel's above answer: I also figured out recently that:

- declaring the object you want to animate with `Animated.ValueXY`
  instead of `Animated.Value` seems to require using `useRef()` instead
  of `useState()`. `useState()` still works fine with `Animated.Value`
  though.
- in `Animated.View style={...}`, using `getLayout()` on the object you want to animate (translate along X+Y) makes the translation happen with no issues.

So for instance, here is the code snippet (source: [this repo](https://github.com/shevon14/FloatingActionButton-RN/blob/main/button.js)) to animate 1 icon `cloud-upload` (taken from [FontAwesome glossary](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/glyphmaps/FontAwesome.json)) with `Animated.Value` :

```
const FloatingButton = () => {

  const [icon_1] = useState(new Animated.Value(40));
  const [pop, setPop] = useState(false);

  const popIn = () => {
    setPop(true);
    Animated.timing(icon_1, {
      toValue: 130,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
    }

    const popOut = () => {
    setPop(false);
    Animated.timing(icon_1, {
      toValue: 40,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
    }

  return(
    <View style={{
      flex: 1
    }}>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.circle, { bottom: icon_1}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Icon name="cloud-upload" size={25} color="#FFFF" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.circle}
        onPress={() => {
          pop === false ? popIn() : popOut();
        }}
      >
        <Icon name="plus" size={25} color="#FFFF" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )

}

export default FloatingButton;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  circle: {
     backgroundColor: '#f52d56',
     width: 60,
     height: 60,
     position: 'absolute',
     bottom: 40,
     right: 40,
     borderRadius: 50,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
  }
})
```

and here is a working equivalent I wrote with `Animated.ValueXY`, with random values used for the initial and final values of `x` and `y` - note:

- the use of `useRef().current` below when defining `icon_1` initially
- the use of `getLayout()` method in `Animated.View` style

```
const FloatingButtonXY = () => {

  const initialXY = {
    x: 44,
    y: 260
  };

  const icon_1 = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY(initialXY)).current;

  const [pop, setPop] = useState(false);

  const popIn = () => {
    setPop(true);

    Animated.timing(icon_1, {
      toValue: {x: 100, y: -100},
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
    }

  const popOut = () => {
    setPop(false);

    Animated.timing(icon_1, {
      toValue: initialXY,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
    }

return(
    <View style={{
      flex: 1,
    }}>
     <Animated.View style={[styles.circle, icon_1.getLayout()]}>
       <TouchableOpacity>
         <Icon name="cloud-upload" size={25} color="#FFFF" />
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </Animated.View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.circle}
        onPress={() => {
          pop === false ? popIn() : popOut();
        }}
      >
        <Icon name="plus" size={25} color="#FFFF" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )

}

export default FloatingButtonXY;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  circle: {
     backgroundColor: '#f52d56',
     width: 60,
     height: 60,
     position: 'absolute',
     bottom: 40,
     right: 40,
     borderRadius: 50,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
  }
})
```

if the menu you want to design is made up of several icons - which is usually the case - then you can copy/paste the `Animated.timing` and `Animated.View` parts as many times as there are icons to display. For an example of working "flower menu" inspired by the above repo, I've forked and refactored it a little [here](https://github.com/alicecommits/FloatingActionButton-RN-petals).

Note: in a fully functional app with a map in background of the main screen, in order for the animation to work, my `FloatingActionButton` component needed to be encapsulated in a `<View></View>` tag that has a "container styling", example [here](https://github.com/alicecommits/tracking-app-RN-template/blob/main/screens/HomeScreen.js).